# Could not find com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.6

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add this dependency 
 `com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.6.` in an android app. On building the project I am having this error critically

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.6.
     Required by:
         push:app:unspecified
```

Please what am I doing wrong. Kindly assist

Comment: Try to find the latest version of dependency if it is exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latest version of dependency is :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
}
```

and don't forgot to add `maven` repo in the project-level `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

for more information [check here](https://github.com/scottyab/showhidepasswordedittext)